# ReactJs - Add unique Component every time during onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am in the process of learning React and Redux. Currently I am working on a project where I need to append a component on button click.

1. New Component should be added down the previous component
2. Previously added component contains the data added and it should not be refreshed while adding a new component.

I tried to search but all the solutions are recommending to use a List and incrementing the count on every click.

This is my requirement diagram:

[image]

Update: 
I have added my code which I tried in the below JS Fiddle.

While appending the new component, the data modified in the existing component should be retained.

https://jsfiddle.net/np7u6L1w/

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = { addComp: [] }
}
addComp() { // Onclick function for 'Add Component' Button
//this.setState({ addComp: !this.state.addComp })
this.setState({
    addComp: [...this.state.addComp, <Stencil />]
});
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div class="contentLeft"><h2>Workflows:</h2>
    <Stencil />
    {this.state.addComp.map((data, index) => {
            { data }        
    })}
    </div>
    <div class="contentRight" >
      <button name="button" onClick={this.addComp.bind(this)} title="Append new component on to the end of the list">Add Component</button>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: give it a try and then when you run into issues you can post it to be helped.

Comment: Use state to store component details and data as an array. in render(). loop the array and render component.  Update state when button is clicked, react will take care of rest.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add the code of your solution so that the community can help you with any issues you come up with.

Comment: Downvoted , please issue all the codes you tried for us to help you even better.

Comment: I have added js fiddle where I have pasted my tried code.

Comment: @xSkrappy - Updated the question with example code which I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code is Updated:**
You can do something like that

```
// New state
this.state = {
   appendedCompsCount: 0
}

// Outside render()
handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({
    appendedCompsCount: this.state.appendedCompsCount + 1
  }) 
}

getAppendedComponents = () => {
  let appendedComponents = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.appendedCompsCount; i++) {
     appendedComponents.push(
       <AppendedComponents key={i} />
     )
  }
  return appendedComponents;
}

// In render()
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click here</button>
{
   this.getAppendedComponents() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sharma. But I need to append components on every button click, not hide and show.

Comment: I have updated the code, you can check. Instead of count, you can directly put the 'AppendedComponents' in the state also, another approach to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe when added new child, you want animation to work.

this is the best method **react-transition-group**

example: https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group

Comment: No I don't need animation. But i just want to append same components to dom on every button click.